# Capturar e criar array de objetos por checkbox Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, ionic, ionic3

A minha dúvida acredito que seja algo simples, porém eu não estou conseguindo chegar a uma lógica..

Eu possuo uma aplicação de vendas, a qual tem uma lista de produtos sendo retornada do firebase, e cada produto deste tem um checkbox ao lado dele para marcação. A lógica é, o cliente seleciona o produto no checkbox e dispara um evento que captura este produto e eu passo ele por NAVPARAMS para a tela de vendas. Até ai tudo bem.

O problema é o seguinte, existirá o caso do cliente selecionar mais de um item por vez para fazer a venda para agilizar o processo. Entendo que eu precisaria criar um array e passar esse array para a próxima tela. Porém eu não estou conseguindo fazer isso, alguém poderia me dar algum exemplo de código ou sugerir alguma melhoria ? Vou deixar abaixo o meu código ts e meu html.

**TS:**

```
//FUNÇÃO QUE CAPTURA O VALOR DO CHECKBOX E ARMAZENA NA VARIÁVEL PARA PASSAR COMO PARAMETRO

produtoEscolhido(produto, isChecked){
    if(isChecked) {
      this.produtosEscolhidos = produto;
      let produtos = [this.produtosEscolhidos];
      console.log(produtos);
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
//LISTA DE PRODUTOS COM O EVENTO PRODUTO ESCOLHIDO QUE CAPTURA O ITEM QUE O USUÁRIO SELECIONOU

<ion-list *ngFor="let produto of produtosLista | async">
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>{{produto.descricao}}</ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="produto.selecionado" (ionChange)="produtoEscolhido(produto, $event.checked)"></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>

    <button ion-button color="dark" (click)="escolherProdutos()">Escolher</button>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Em vez de capturar os valores do checkbox no `ionchange`, você pode capturar no `button`, na função `escolherProdutos()`, por exemplo. Você pode verificar todos os seus produtos e identificar quais estão selecionados, para em seguida passá-los como parâmetro.

```
escolherProdutos(){

  let produtosEscolhidos = [];

  for(let i=0; i<this.produtosLista.length; i++){
    if (this.produtosLista[i].selecionado){
      produtosEscolhidos.push(this.produtosLista[i]);
    }    
  }

}
```

Comment: Renata eu fiz como você passou ai, mas nesse caso o que ficaria dentro do meu ionchange? 

  escolherProdutos(){
    let produtosEscolhidos = []; 
    for(let i=0; i < this.produtosLista.length; i++){
      if (this.produtosLista[i].selecionado){
        produtosEscolhidos.push(this.produtosLista[i]);
        console.log("Os produtos escolhidos são " +this.produtosLista[i]);
      }else{
        console.log("erro");
      }    
    }
  
  }

No meu console.log não está retornando nada..

Comment: Você não precisa incluir nenhuma função no seu `ionchange`. Como você vai aguardar o usuário escolher todos os itens que ele precisa, a função ficaria, por exemplo, no `button`, que você já tem após o `ion-list`.

Comment: Ok, vou fazer mais uns testes. Acompanhando o código que mandei acima, deveria me retornar algo no console correto ? Ou eu fiz alguma coisa errada?

Comment: Eu faria uma pequena alteração, deixando o console.log após o for. escolherProdutos(){

  let produtosEscolhidos = [];

  for(let i=0; i<this.produtosLista.length; i++){
    if (this.produtosLista[i].selecionado){
      produtosEscolhidos.push(this.produtosLista[i]);
    }    
  } 
  console.log("Os produtos escolhidos são " + produtosEscolhidos); 
}

Comment: Quando eu tento adicionar a propriedade length ao código, ele me retorna o seguinte erro de sintaxe : 

[ts] Property 'length' does not exist on type 'Observable<Produtos[]>'.

E executando a função em um botão de teste, ele não chama nada no console. Eu acredito que ele não esteja percorrendo a lista, por conta desta propriedade. Alguma coisa que eu possa fazer para resolver?

Comment: Eu atualizei algumas coisas no meu código : 

//A Lista está na mesma tela de vendas, ou seja nao preciso mais passar parametro, apenas mostrar os itens em um card e enviar ao banco de dados 

      <ion-list *ngFor="let produto of produtosLista | async">
        <ion-item> 
          <ion-label>{{produto.descricao}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{produto.preco}}</ion-label>
          <ion-checkbox></ion-checkbox>
        </ion-item>
        <button ion-button outline color="dark" class="botao-add">
          <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-list>

Answer (score -2):

Esta duvida sanou outra que tinha aqui... Valeu pela resposta!!!

```
escolherProdutos(){

  let produtosEscolhidos = [];

for(let i=0; i<this.produtosLista.length; i++){
    if (this.produtosLista[i].selecionado){
    produtosEscolhidos.push(this.produtosLista[i]);
    }    
  }
}
```